# After service worker update, delivering rate of push notifications decreased from 50% to 10%. How to investigate why?

Tags: push-notification, service-worker

I updated (modified code) service worker  on my server. Before this update, the delivering rate of push notifications was 50%, now it's 10%. I don't understand why.

I used it in the "Chome-49" way:

- send batch of IDs to `https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send`
- GCM calls my service workers
- then my service workers send a request to my server for payload by calling server url

Before I changed service worker, about 50% of service workers asked server for payload, now only 10% do.

I don't understand what's going on. I send the same tokens to GCM, but get 5 times fewer requests from my service workers to my server

What can I do to solve this problem? What could be the reason? How can I investigate or debug this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing here that

> updated (modified code) service worker

means that there is a substantial change in your SW code and how it handles caching.  My guess there is how you wrote the SW code and somehow the SW is not being updated properly.  It also looks like that 10% delivery rate is coming from new users instead of your previously accumulated users.  It seems that you need to purge the old service workers on your previous users.

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44665092/how-to-cache-bust-sw-toolbox/#44682310) answer.  I haven't tried it our yet.  But it sounds like a viable solution.